# Google documents mime type

Tags: android

I am trying to get access to a Google doc on `Android 4.4` using `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, but the documents in the Google drive chooser appear grayed out (not selectable). I can get to the doc/docx files on Google drive just fine, but not to Google documents. The mime types I specified match the ones listed in [Google Drive's Supported MIME Types](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/mime-types).

Here is the code snippet (running on `Android 4.4`):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, new String[]{
        "application/msword",
        "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text",
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template",
        "application/vnd.google-apps.document",
        "application/vnd.google-apps.kix",
});
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Comment: Try adding `application/vnd.google-apps.file`?

Comment: Adding application/vnd.google-apps.file didn't help. Google docs are still grayed out.

Comment: Hmm, I have got the same problem when set `Drive.DriveApi.newOpenFileActivityBuilder().setMimeType(new String[]{"*/*"})`, only setting specific mime types helped so far.

Comment: Got solved??? any solution kindly share it

Answer (score -1):

Google Drive supports multiple file types, and "Google Doc" is only one such file type. I suspect that your Google Drive may contain other file types. For example, depending on your use case, you should consider including the following MIME types:

```
application/vnd.google-apps.presentation
application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet
application/vnd.google-apps.drawing
```

However, that will not cover all the file types that are possible. You need to understand what file types you want to support and include all their MIME types.

Or, if you want to support *all* openable file types, you should just not specify EXTRA_MIME_TYPES at all.

Comment: Doesn't work (Google Docs still grayed out). As I mentioned in my question, I am specifically interested in importing Google Docs, not Google Slides, ...etc.

Comment: Actually, what you originally mentioned was "Google documents", which is really a generic term for all Google file types. A "Google Doc" is just one kind of Google  document. My answer was really directly related to your question, as posed. Nevertheless, it does not seem to have worked for your documents.

Comment: The names are confusing. I think now (at least per https://developers.google.com/drive/web/mime-types), Google Docs refers to Word-like files. Unfortunately, I am still stuck with the same problem. Thanks for your suggestion though.